Initialize BehaviorSubject with value from Observable
I was trying to create an item counter for Wishlist Entries in my header area and tried to apply the solutions suggested here (for Cart Items)
Change shopping-cart count in header in Angular
Unfortunately this does not quite cut it for me since the solutions are ignoring that there might be initial Data served as an Observable.
In my case I'm storing the WishlistObjects with StorageMap (@ngx-pwa/local-storage), and that data is only returned as an Observable and I'm not quite sure how to associate that initial Data with the BehaviorSubject in the Service that is supposed to keep track of modifications. That's why I came up with this idea of having two seperate observables, that I combine...
COMPONENT: 
export class WishlistLinkComponent{

  merged$: Observable<number> = combineLatest([this.wishListService.getWishList(),this.wishListService.getCartCount()]).pipe(
    map(([wishlist, count]) => {
      console.log('wishlist: ',wishlist);
      console.log('count: ',count);
      return count ?? (wishlist.entries?.length ?? 0);
    })
  )

  constructor(protected wishListService: WishListService) {}

}


SERVICE:
export class EmvAnonymousWishListService {
  constructor(
    private storage: StorageMap,
    private productService: ProductService
  ) { }

  private cartSubj:BehaviorSubject<number | undefined> = new BehaviorSubject<number| undefined>(undefined);


  getCartCount(): Observable<number> {
    return this.cartSubj.asObservable();
  }
  
    getWishList(): Observable<Cart> {
    return this.storage.get('wishlist')
      .pipe(
        switchMap((productCodes: string[]) => this.productService.getProducts(productCodes)),
    );
  }
  
    addEntry(productCode: string): void {
    this.this.storage.get('wishlist').subscribe(productCodes => {
        productCodes.push(productCode);
        this.cartSubj.next(productCodes.length)
        //store Logic...
    });
  }
  
      removeEntry(productCode: string): void {
    this.this.storage.get('wishlist').subscribe(productCodes => {
        const filteredProductCodes = productCodes.filter((code: string) => {
          return code !== productCode;
        });
        this.cartSubj.next(productCodes.length)
        //store Logic...
    });
  }
  
}

I know this is ugly, but I don't know how to handle a scenario like this, with only one observable covering everything.

you can streamline it like:
Use ReplaySubject: Instead of BehaviorSubject, you can use ReplaySubject(1) to ensure the initial state from StorageMap is captured and updates are properly emitted.
Ensure Initial Storage Data: You want to initialize the cartSubj with the current state of the wishlist, so it can start with the correct count before any modifications are made.
  // Service
  export class EmvAnonymousWishListService {
    constructor(
      private storage: StorageMap,
      private productService: ProductService
    ) {
      this.initializeCartCount();
    }

    private cartSubj: ReplaySubject<number> = new ReplaySubject<number>(1);

    // Initialize cart count based on stored wishlist
    private initializeCartCount() {
      this.storage.get<string[]>('wishlist').pipe(
        map(productCodes => productCodes?.length ?? 0)
      ).subscribe(count => {
        this.cartSubj.next(count);
      });
    }

    getCartCount(): Observable<number> {
      return this.cartSubj.asObservable();
    }

    getWishList(): Observable<Cart> {
      return this.storage.get('wishlist').pipe(
        switchMap((productCodes: string[]) => this.productService.getProducts(productCodes))
      );
    }

    addEntry(productCode: string): void {
      this.storage.get<string[]>('wishlist').subscribe(productCodes => {
        const updatedCodes = productCodes ? [...productCodes, productCode] : [productCode];
        this.storage.set('wishlist', updatedCodes).subscribe(() => {
          this.cartSubj.next(updatedCodes.length);
        });
      });
    }

    removeEntry(productCode: string): void {
      this.storage.get<string[]>('wishlist').subscribe(productCodes => {
        const updatedCodes = productCodes?.filter(code => code !== productCode) || [];
        this.storage.set('wishlist', updatedCodes).subscribe(() => {
          this.cartSubj.next(updatedCodes.length);
        });
      });
    }
  }




  // Component
  export class WishlistLinkComponent {
    merged$: Observable<number>;

    constructor(protected wishListService: EmvAnonymousWishListService) {
      this.merged$ = combineLatest([
        this.wishListService.getWishList(),
        this.wishListService.getCartCount()
      ]).pipe(
        map(([wishlist, count]) => {
          console.log('wishlist: ', wishlist);
          console.log('count: ', count);
          return count ?? (wishlist.entries?.length ?? 0);
        })
      );
    }
  }

Key improvements:
ReplaySubject(1): This replaces BehaviorSubject to store the latest emitted value, even if no subscriber was present during the emission.
Initial Count: initializeCartCount ensures the wishlist count is correctly initialized from storage.
Updates after Add/Remove: After adding or removing entries, the updated count is pushed to cartSubj, and subscribers will get the updated count.

brilliant, that works well! Only concern. Don't I need to unsubscribe too or is that irrelevant for such global tracking Services?
Also I noticed that BehaviorSubject still would work as well. So far I don't understand what exclusive benefit ReplaySubject delivers in general.

ReplaySubject  can "replay" multiple past values (you can specify how many values to replay). It’s useful when you want new subscribers to get more than just the latest value. In your case, ReplaySubject(1) is effectively similar to BehaviorSubject because it’s only holding one value.
Use it when you want new subscribers to receive more than one previous value (for e.g., to replay a sequence of events).

You could try using a tap to update the initial value of the behaviour subject and this will take care of the initial value being set.
getWishList(): Observable<Cart> {
return this.storage.get('wishlist')
  .pipe(
    switchMap((productCodes: string[]) => this.productService.getProducts(productCodes)),
    tap((wishlist: any) => {
      this.cartSubj.next(wishlist.entries?.length);
    }
);

The component can read this data and update it.

I am not sure what is your concern, but I am under the impression that it's all about counting, why don't you make use of rxjs count operator?
for example:
of(1, 2, 3).pipe(count()).subscribe(console.log);

this will log "3". If this does not answer your concern, please collaborate more to be able to help you.
